# how to use datepart in SQL sERVER?

Tags: sql-server, sas

I needed help in writing this SAS code in SQL server. I am interested in knowing how to use the the datepart in SQL Server. I included the whole query as it might help in understanding what I am doing.

How can I rewrite the last where clause containing the datepart(written in SAS)  to SQL server?

```
    create table step1 as

SELECT a.*,ar.Productid,ar.pricelistid
  FROM AB a
inner join BB ar
    on a.someid = ar.someid

;



create table step2 as

SELECT a.*, ar.price
  FROM step1 a
inner join XX ar
    on a.Productid = ar.Productid
          and a.pricelistid = ar.pricelistid

          where datepart(startdatum)< '01DEC2013'd and
( datepart(enddate) = . or datepart(enddate)>= '01DEC2013'd)
```

;

Comment: what are the types of startdatum and enddate : I would guess a non nullable DateTime and a nullable datetime, but... could you confirm ?

Comment: so what does `datepart(enddate) = .` mean in SAS ?

Comment: and are they datetime ? Both ? Both non nullable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a date type, only datetime.  It isn't therefore necessary to use any datepart function, you can simply put '01Dec2013' which is equivalent to '01Dec2013 00:00:00'.  There is a datepart function in sql server, this returns a single unit from a datetime, e.g. year or month or day.

You where clause in sql server should look something like :

```
where 
    startdatum<'01DEC2013' 
    and
    ( enddate is null 
      or 
      enddate>='01DEC2013')
```